# Getting the input tag(s) and setting them as unchecked

Tags: javascript

I want to write a java script function which will get the input tag(s) with type as "checkbox" from the td and mark them unchecked. Following is the jsp code:

```
<td id="uncheckedByDefault" align=center class=listTypeOne>
    <% if (priv.getViewPrivilege() == 1) { %>
    <input name="view" type="checkbox" value='<%= priv.getAttributeId() %>' checked>                     
    <% } else { %>
    <input name="view" type="checkbox" value='<%= priv.getAttributeId()%>'>
    <% } %>
</td>
```

Now here the td has the id="uncheckedByDefault". I want to get all the input tag(s) and set them as unchecked. Can anybody tell how can I do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not changing the above code? Why using javascript?

Comment: @NOX I posted my answer as JSP code for Java. It seems that he used Java, because he is using `<%` tags, but tagged his question as `JavaScript` and proposed to retag it into `Java`, but he declined. I'm not really sure what language is OP using or what language want to use to solve his problem. It's really unclear.

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX He said: `I want to get all the input tag(s) and set them as unchecked.`. So just delete the `if/else` block at all and remove `checked` attribute from the code! I think that something is missing here.

Comment: @NOX But it's pretty useless to do that in `JavaScript` when you already know it from the server. I mean, that the code will work if he just set his conditions properly. You can solve this in both languages, as I said in a comment somewhere in this post, but if you know in your JSP if they are checked or not, why using `Javascript` to do that? Thats why I suggested to change tag into `Java` and change it into the JSP. Also, you can't know in `JavaScript` if they are checked or unchecked as you can do in JSP because of your Java Object. You will set all unchecked via `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
inputs = document.getElementById('uncheckedByDefault').getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
        // deal with inputs[index] element.
       inputs[index].checked=false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing it and it worked. but the only problem that I am facing one more issues because of this and that is all the check boxes on the page are getting unchecked. Now I have made sure that I have used the id only for this td and no other td on the page. Any reason that comes to your mind why this should be happening? Is it something because we are specifying input to .getElementsByTagName() method?

Comment: Your question was to make all the checkboxes inside td with id `uncheckedByDefault` as unchecked. So this is the code for that only. Which checkbox you don't want to be unchecked isn't specified.

Comment: So ideally the above code should alter only those check boxes that belong to the td with the id="uncheckedByDefault". But the thing is that all the check boxes on the page irrespective of the td's are getting unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your problem, but I will give it a try.

First of all, you can print elements into your web page with a `<% ... %>` (I will show how in my answer), so you don't have to set a condition into `<% ... %>`, print an element... etc. All in the same Java function.

Secondly, you can access to your `Object` properties without calling your getters. Aren't needed at all if you want to set his value into an specific field. (i.e.) `<input type="text" name="clientName" value="${client.clientName}" />`

Here is my proposal for your question:

```
<td id="uncheckedByDefault" align=center class=listTypeOne>
    <%
        if (priv.getViewPrivilege() == 1) {
            out.println("<input name='view' type='checkbox' + 
            value=" + priv.getAttributeId() + " checked = 'checked'>");
        } else {
            out.println("<input name='view' type='checkbox' + 
            value=" + priv.getAttributeId() + ">");
        }
    %>
</td>
```

Report if it worked or it's not what you wanted.

**UPDATE**

If you want them all unchecked, because of your element `id` attribute suggests it. Why do you want to check your Object properties to set it `checked` or not? Just add your element and don't set it a checked property.

`<input name='view' type='checkbox' value="${priv.attributeId}">`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function you need, call it whenever you want:

```
function uncheckAll(){
    var inputsContainer = document.getElementById('uncheckedByDefault');
    var allInputs = inputsContainer.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var len = allInputs.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
         if(allInputs[i].type == 'checkbox'){
         allInputs[i].checked = false;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get a list of all of the elements you're interested in, then you need to perform some action on them. I've added the forEachNode function, since the querySelectorAll function doesn't actually return an array - it returns a nodeList which has similar syntax and functionality as an array, but omits the forEach function.

Note: a checkbox is checked if it has the attribute checked. The actual value of the attribute is not used - it's just it's presence or lack thereof that dictates the check-state. As such, you could write anything rather than 0 to the checked attribute.

EDIT: The above note is incorrect. Both the 'checked' attribute as visible in the html and the 'checked' member variable control the state. I've updated the uncheck and check functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
}

/*
     func to be called takes 3 variables. currentElement, currentIndex, nodeList the element belongs to.
*/
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}
/*
function uncheck(elem)
{
    elem.removeAttribute('checked');
}

function check(elem)
{
    elem.setAttribute('checked',0);
}
*/

function uncheck(elem)
{
    elem.checked = false;
    elem.removeAttribute('checked');
}

function check(elem)
{
    elem.checked = true;
    elem.setAttribute('checked',0);
}



function checkAll()
{
    var checkBoxElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    forEachNode(checkBoxElements, check);
}

function uncheckAll()
{
    var checkBoxElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    forEachNode(checkBoxElements, uncheck);
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='uncheckAll()'>Uncheck all</button>
    <button onclick='checkAll()'>Check all</button>
    <br>
    <input type='checkbox'/>CB 1
    <br>
    <input type='checkbox'/>CB 2
    <br>
    <input type='checkbox'/>CB 3
    <br>
    <input type='checkbox'/>CB 4
    <br>
    <input type='checkbox'/>CB 5
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer (i'm not the OP) and will no downvote, but this is not what he spected (I think). He is working with Java, but this question is bad tagged. Maybe I'm wrong, but this is what I think. I'm sorry :(

Comment: It's really no problem. No need to be sorry. I had the more-or-less same thoughts, except I'd figured you'd missed the javascript tag and the OP had provided irrelevant jsp code. *Off topic joke* How many internet forum users does it take to screw in a light-bulb? 100. 1 to do the job and 99 to say how it should have been done. :-)

Comment: Haha nice one joke :D Also, I didn't missed the `javascript` tag, but he didn't said in his question in what language want to do it and posted his JSP code. It's pretty unclear to answer correctly, because you can give solutions in both languages.

Comment: :) Glad you liked it. I just went on word 6 and 7 of the question. I.e "I want to write a ***java script*** function". Also, the text after the code "I want to ***get*** all the input tag(s) and set them as unchecked." Hmm. Oh well, C'est la vie! Only the OP knows what the desired intention is. :-)

Comment: Yeah, but as I said in a comment in main question, you can do that in both ways (`JavaScript` or `Java` into JSP). The question now is that if you are already printing your checkboxes via JSP, checking your Object properties for your checkboxes to set them checked or unchecked, why don't do that in JSP directly? If you want all unchecked, as your `id` attribute suggests, why do you set an `if` in your `<td>` to check if it is checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var allInputs = document.getElementById("uncheckedByDefault").getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
    if (allInputs[i].getAttribute("type") == 'checkbox') {
        allInputs[i].removeAttribute("checked");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'd thought too. However, if the user check a box with the mouse, code to remove the checked attribute didn't clear the check. You may see that in the example I gave. (Which I had to edit after realizing that although it 'should' work, it didn't)

Comment: In that case you may use `allInputs[i].checked = false;`

Comment: Indeed. Using both methods means the page will save to disk the same way its rendered when the save btn is hit. Good for saving form answers.